# Maximal number of $S_n$-conjugates living in a hyperplane

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra

Let $v=(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ where the $a_i$ are distinct and positive. For $\sigma\in S_n$, let $\sigma(v)=(a_{\sigma(1)},\dots,a_{\sigma(n)})$. For any hyperplane $H$ through the origin, let $m_H$ be the number of $\sigma\in S_n$ such that $\sigma(v)\in H$. What is $\max_H m_H$?

I suspect that the answer is $(n-1)!$. Notice that if $\sigma\in S_{n-1}$, then the $(n-1)!$ vectors $\sigma(v)$ are all contained in the hyperplane $(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i)x_n=a_n\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_i$.

Comment: Do you mean the maximum over all possible choices of $v$, or the maximum as a function of $v$?  (Also, are your hyperplanes always through the origin?)

Comment: Good point. I edited the question.

Comment: If $n$ is even and $v=(1,2,\dots,n)$, then the condition $\frac{n-2}2(x_1+x_2)=(x_3+\dots+x_n)$, equivalent with $x_1+x_2=n+1$, is satisfied on $(n-2)!n$ points.

Comment: Your edit still doesn't seem directly to address my question:  are you looking for $\max_H m_H(v)$ as a function of $v$, or for $\max_v \max_H m_H(v)$?

Comment: Understanding $\max_H m_H(v)$ would be ideal, but I would be happy even knowing the answer to $\max_v\max_H m_H(v)$.

Comment: Thank you Ilya. In the case when $n$ is even, do you know if $\max_v \max_H m_H(v)=(n-2)!n$?